# How to write Dynamic locator in Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am having problem in using dynamic locator.
Here is my Xpath: `//*["@id=row"+${index}+"gridAlerts_AssignedToMe']/div[4]/a"`

```
Name: Xpath
Condition: Equals
Value: id("row${index}gridAlerts_AssignedToMe")/div[4]/a
Detect By Property: Check box is checked.
```

this is my script:

```
for (def index : (0..5)) {
def val = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('HomePage/AlertIdLocators', [('{index}') : index]))
}
```

I am expecting the index value should be replaced by 0 to 5 on every iteration.

But this is not happening. Here is my Log

```
11-30-2017 11:42:12 AM - [FAILED] - Test Cases/MyAlerts_LoopStatement FAILED because (of) Unable to get text of object 'Object Repository/HomePage/AlertIdLocators' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/HomePage/AlertIdLocators' located by 'By.xpath: id("row${index}gridAlerts_AssignedToMe")/div[4]/a' not found)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here an example of correct use of parametric TestObject:

```
int rowIndex = 1
TestObject myObject =   findTestObject('Object Repository/GENERICI/Tabella Risultati Ricerca GENERICA/voceDiAzione_byRow_byCol_byActionName',[('row'):rowIndex,('col'):8,('action'):'Elimina'])
```

The TestObject definition
[image]

In your case the xpath value is something like this: `id("row${index}gridAlerts_AssignedToMe")/div[4]/a`

Answer (score 1):

That is not a correct Xpath in your case. The reason why the final Xpath still not parse ${index} variable into a actual number because you enclosed it in double quotes, so your Xpath should be like this:

```
id("row$"+{index}+"gridAlerts_AssignedToMe")/div[4]/a
```

Comment: $refers to variable. I guess you are not given correct..
 ["@id=row"+${index}+"gridAlerts_AssignedToMe"]/div[4]/a

Comment: Ah sorry it should be this: 
id("row"+${index}+"gridAlerts_AssignedToMe")/div[4]/a

Comment: that also not working.. It seems Katalon is having issue on dealing run time variable

Comment: It works on my side, please see my [images](https://imgur.com/a/bfc7p) .

Comment: Hi, I looked your screenshot. It seems that working as I expected.. Did you add any Object Parameters? Or Just locators and Index is hard coded? Can you please confirm? Will this work if index is supplied from for loop?

Comment: Well I've tried the same scenario and the same script from yours => It still works for me, please see my [images](https://imgur.com/a/papDN). Do you have the same setup? Please note that I use my setup on BASIC mode

Comment: your screenshot helped me.. i am accepting this answer